# Accepted answer on rep page not aligned with background

Tags: bug, design, user-interface

As one can see in the screenshot below, the background is not aligned with the [+15] on the rep page for an accept, and lets the text "bleed"(for lack of better terminology) into the rest of the page:

[image]

I've tried to verify this by creating a new Firefox(latest version) profile and doing nothing other than logging in via Google OpenID and visiting this page. The zoom level is at default and there are no plugins other than the one Ubuntu pre-preinstalls on Firefox(Disabling it does not help).

Comment: What browser?  Were you at the default zoom level?  The site gets a bit wonky if you mess around with zoom levels.

Comment: @Zoredache I'll edit with these details. Sorry.

Comment: With all the other bugs the system has something as trivial as a very minor cosmetic issue is unlikely to even get looked at.